Social Login with WebFlux OAuth2
I am working on a spring boot microservice project that uses oauth2 following a YouTube tutorial that utilizes Keycloak for authentication. Instead of using Keycloak, I opted to configure Google OAuth2 as the authentication mechanism by adding the Google Client ID and Secret ID obtained from the Google Developer Console.
Despite this configuration, I am still encountering issues. My intended outcome is to successfully make a service call through the API Gateway, which should prompt the Google login page for authentication. After a successful login, I expect to be redirected back to my defined endpoint.
SecurityConfig.java
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.reactive.EnableWebFluxSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.SecurityWebFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity serverHttpSecurity, ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository) {
        serverHttpSecurity
                .csrf(ServerHttpSecurity.CsrfSpec::disable)
                .authorizeExchange(exchange ->
                        exchange.pathMatchers("/eureka/**")
                                .permitAll()
                                .anyExchange()
                                .authenticated())
                .oauth2Login(oauth2 -> oauth2
                        .clientRegistrationRepository(clientRegistrationRepository));
        return serverHttpSecurity.build();
    }
}

pom.xml
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>io.zipkin.reporter2</groupId>
          <artifactId>zipkin-reporter-brave</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
        </dependency>

application.properties
spring.application.name=api-gateway
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://eureka:password@localhost:8761/eureka
app.eureka-server=localhost

## Product Service Route
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].id=product-service
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri=lb://product-service
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[0]=Path=/api/product

## Order Service Route
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].id=order-service
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].uri=lb://order-service
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].predicates[0]=Path=/api/order

## Discover Server Route
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[2].id=discovery-server
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[2].uri=http://eureka:password@${app.eureka-server}:8761
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[2].predicates[0]=Path=/eureka/web
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[2].filters[0]=SetPath=/

## Discover Server Static Resources Route
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[3].id=discovery-server-static
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[3].uri=http://eureka:password@${app.eureka-server}:8761
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[3].predicates[0]=Path=/eureka/**

#spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri= http://localhost:8080/realms/spring-boot-microservices-realm

spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.client-id= 186452584986-77gtfh20v3k0thtskoti1akgvgoclhbt.apps.googleusercontent.com
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.client-secret= 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
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.scope=openid,profile,email
server.servlet.session.cookie.same-site=lax

management.zipkin.tracing.endpoint=http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans
management.tracing.sampling.probability=1.0

# Actuator Prometheus Endpoint
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include= prometheus
server.port=8181
logging.pattern.level=%5p [${spring.application.name:},%X{traceId:-},%X{spanId:-}]


controller.java
@RequestMapping
@RestController("/hello")
public class ApiGateWayCtrl {
    @GetMapping("/wow")
    public String get(){
        return "hello world!";
    }
}


when i make a call to the endpoint it corectly open the google prompt for the login but after i login with my account instead of redirecting me to the the endpoint it basically show this message
and in the browser console it shows code 302 for the calls to the endpoint and to google.
Could you please provide guidance on how to properly implement this flow with Google OAuth2?
I'm quite new to security with webflux so if my approach is wrong i'm open to hear your thoughts
Thank you.

Don't use Google as OpenID Provider directly, this will prevent you from:

attaching data to users (like roles)
use access tokens on your REST services configured as resource servers (probable cause for your current issues)
easily add more social identity sources (Facebook, Github, ...)

Instead, use an OIDC Provider of your own with Google as an identity source for it. Keycloak does it, just as most other OIDC Providers (Auth0, Okta, Amazon Cognito, ...).
I wrote tutorials that you should read:

getting started with Keycloak and Spring
implementing the OAuth2 BFF pattern with Spring Cloud Gateway: properly use OAuth2 with single-page or mobile applications and Spring REST backends

As you are new to OAuth2, it is important to start with the Keycloak tutorial and to pay special attention to the sections giving some OAuth2 background.
